# Select random sample from list of dictionaries, with value condition

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a **list of dictionaries** like this:

```
list_of_dicts = [
    {'db': 'redshift', 'table': 'metrics', 'prefix': 'abc_'},
    {'db': 'blueshift', 'table': 'colors', 'prefix': 'abc_'},
    {'db': 'orangeshift', 'table': 'people', 'prefix': 'def_'},
    {'db': 'greenshift', 'table': 'money', 'prefix': 'def_'},
    {'db': 'purpleshift', 'table': 'props', 'prefix': 'ghi_'},
    {'db': 'brownshift', 'table': 'stages', 'prefix': 'ghi_'},
...
]
```

How can I **extract N of each prefix**? For example, imagine the above list was large, and I wanted to get back a list of dicts that has **5 of each prefix**. So I would get a list of 15 dicts, 5 dicts with `abc_` prefix, 5 with `def_` and 5 with `ghi_`

The **expected output** would be:

```
result = [
    {'db': 'redshift', 'table': 'metrics', 'prefix': 'abc_'},
    {'db': 'blueshift', 'table': 'colors', 'prefix': 'abc_'},
    {'db': 'orangeshift', 'table': 'people', 'prefix': 'abc_'},
    {'db': 'greenshift', 'table': 'money', 'prefix': 'abc_'},
    {'db': 'purpleshift', 'table': 'props', 'prefix': 'abc_'},
    {'db': 'redshift', 'table': 'metrics', 'prefix': 'def_'},
    {'db': 'blueshift', 'table': 'colors', 'prefix': 'def_'},
    {'db': 'orangeshift', 'table': 'people', 'prefix': 'def_'},
    {'db': 'greenshift', 'table': 'money', 'prefix': 'def_'},
    {'db': 'purpleshift', 'table': 'props', 'prefix': 'def_'},
    {'db': 'redshift', 'table': 'metrics', 'prefix': 'ghi_'},
    {'db': 'blueshift', 'table': 'colors', 'prefix': 'ghi_'},
    {'db': 'orangeshift', 'table': 'people', 'prefix': 'ghi_'},
    {'db': 'greenshift', 'table': 'money', 'prefix': 'ghi_'},
    {'db': 'purpleshift', 'table': 'props', 'prefix': 'ghi_'},
]
```

So 5 dicts for each distinct prefix have been randomly extracted from a large list of dicts.

Answer (score 1):

group the dicts with prefix value as key, and list as value with a defaultdict. Then extract n elements of each (here I sampled 2 random elements from each list), "flatten" the lists if needed with `itertools.chain`

```
import collections,random, itertools

list_of_dicts = [
    {'db': 'redshift', 'table': 'metrics', 'prefix': 'abc_'},
    {'db': 'blueshift', 'table': 'colors', 'prefix': 'abc_'},
    {'db': 'orangeshift', 'table': 'people', 'prefix': 'def_'},
    {'db': 'greenshift', 'table': 'money', 'prefix': 'def_'},
    {'db': 'purpleshift', 'table': 'props', 'prefix': 'ghi_'},
    {'db': 'brownshift', 'table': 'stages', 'prefix': 'ghi_'}
]

d = collections.defaultdict(list)
# group the dicts by prefix
for lst in list_of_dicts:
    d[lst["prefix"]].append(lst)

# pick some dicts in each group & flatten the result
# a rare case where the keys aren't important in that step
result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(random.sample(v,2) for v in d.values()))


print(result)
```

one output:

```
[{'db': 'redshift', 'table': 'metrics', 'prefix': 'abc_'},
  {'db': 'blueshift', 'table': 'colors', 'prefix': 'abc_'},
 {'db': 'greenshift', 'table': 'money', 'prefix': 'def_'},
  {'db': 'orangeshift', 'table': 'people', 'prefix': 'def_'}, 
{'db': 'brownshift', 'table': 'stages', 'prefix': 'ghi_'},
 {'db': 'purpleshift', 'table': 'props', 'prefix': 'ghi_'}]
```